# Can you book Stayover Packages (flight + hotel for stopover + flight) online?

Tags: online-resources, stopovers

> [[Source 2016/8/7:]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76168/13759)  A **transit** is by definition less than 24 hours, with some rare exceptions if the best available connection is longer.
>
> If you want to stay longer, you'll need to look for a **stopover**. These often cost extra (US$100 is typical), although some airlines like Singapore and Emirates offer well-priced stopover packages including hotel, and `usually need to be booked by a travel agency instead of online` [emphasis mine].)
>
> [ [Source 2013/5/29:](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/17733/13759) ] Second, Air Canada (since you mentioned Toronto) has [a special program](http://www.aircanada.com/en/travelinfo/traveller/stopover/index.html) involving connecting through Toronto, Montreal, or Vancouver and getting a hotel night as part of a package. (Free if you are on a high fare, $49 otherwise.) You also get lounge access at the stopover airport. It's pretty enticing for someone in your situation.

Are there exceptions to the grey above? I would be stupefied if no online search engine can accomplish the grey above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, at least for Singapore Airlines:

> Singapore Stopover Holiday (SSH)
>
> On the way to your destination, experience the sights and sounds of multicultural Singapore – with a stay at our selection of 3- or 4-star hotels, admission to over 15 tourist attractions, complimentary rides on the SIA Hop-on Bus and more.

You have to book a flight with a stopover and then add the "stopover package" to your booking. Not as convenient as doing it in one go, but at least you don't have to visit a travel agent.